# How to catch exception thrown by save method of JpaRepository interface

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a SpingBoot project that uses Spring Data Jpa as its repository level abstraction. I have a repository that extends JpaRepository interface. I call the `save()` method from within my Service layer as follows :

```
myCustomeRepository.save(new ObjectXYZ(abc,xyz));
```

I also observed that the `save()` method inherited from the **CrudRepository** throws `IllegalArgumentException` when receiving `null` entities.

Should I go ahead and try to catch the **IllegalArgumentException** in my Service layer ?i.e.

```
try{
            myCustomeRepository.save(new ObjectXYZ(abc,xyz));
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException iae){

        }
```

**NOTE:** I have already implemented validation(**@NotEmpty**) at the DTO level using **Hibernate Validator**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IllegalArgumentException` extends `RuntimeException`, so the compiler will not force you to catch it.

Whether you catch it or not depends on what you want to do if it occurs:

- If you expect it to never happen, because of the validation you have in place, then don't catch it. If it does happen (e.g. there's a problem with your validation) then your application will fail and you will find out that there's a problem.
- If it indicates that the client has passed bad data to your service layer, you could catch it and do whatever your service layer does to report invalid data to its clients, or you could just not catch it, and (assuming you are writing a web application) have a global mapping of the exception to a 400 bad request status.
- What you should *not* do is catch it and ignore it, because then you will have difficulty figuring out what is wrong with your system if it is ever thrown.

Comment: typo in your post: 400, not 401.